# Cannot exec simple javascript file into Truffle

Tags: ethereum, truffle

I have a file x.js which works fine on it's own.

```js
function test() {
    console.log("test");
}
```

I want to include this into truffle, so I do the following

```
truffle(development)> exec ./x.js
Using network 'development'.

TypeError: fn is not a function
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/packages/truffle-require/require.js:128:1
```

I do not understand the error, how to fix?

Comment: Use `truffle exec` https://medium.com/@timothyjcoulter/truffle-tricks-for-ethereum-development-dispelling-8-myths-first-impressions-880f66bf3320#69be

Comment: But I want to import the function - i.e. use it on the console command line.

Answer (score 5):

Truffle requires your script to export a function. Try something like this:

```
module.exports = function(callback) {
    console.log("test");
    callback();
}
```

And check out the docs: https://www.trufflesuite.com/docs/truffle/getting-started/writing-external-scripts